# Colors withOpacity : Const variables must be initialized with a constant value

Tags: flutter

When I try to use the expression

```dart
const Color someColor= Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0);
```

it throws the error

```
Const variables must be initialized with a constant value
```

What has happened here and how can I get around this error?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

> Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
>
> The analyzer produces this diagnostic when a value that isn’t
> statically known to be a constant is assigned to a variable that’s
> declared to be a const variable.

[Learn more](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=const_initialized_with_non_constant_value#const_initialized_with_non_constant_value)

Use `final` instead.

```dart
final Color someColor= Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0);
```

---

**Edit**

If you must have a constant Color with opacity,
Try ARGB instead

```dart
Color.fromARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b,)
```

Comment: That is a solution when the parent widget is a final widget, but it is only a constant widget. It then gives me the answer ```Error: Not a constant expression.```

Comment: `withOpacity(double opacity)` is function which isn't returning a constant value. Try `Color.fromARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b,) `

Comment: Can you show how this color const is used in that constant parent widget? @Uwe.Schneider